# Magento 2 Installation Issue

Tags: magento2, install

I have extracted the tar.gz from the official Magento website and uploaded it to my server without any problems. However, when I try to access the Magento installation I am shown an 'Autoload Error' where it seems to be trying to autoload files from `/magento2/app/code/*/*/cli_commands.php` where `magento2` is the subdirectory in the `public_html` folder.

I'm not quite sure why it would be looking in this location as the `/app/code/` folder no longer exists in Magento 2.

Anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Did you follow this installation guide here? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html

Comment: @AnnaVölkl Yeah I did follow that but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you be more specific about which tar file your used? with or without sample data? Also have you set up file permissions as expected?

Comment: @Maddy I have tried to both tar files with and without sample data but I am still seeing the same error message. The file permissions should be correct but I will double check them all again.